# How do you remove the grb (grub 1) mbr from inside Suse Linux 12

Tags: linux, suse, grub

How do you remove the grb (grub 1) mbr from inside Suse Linux 12?
I have tried this as stated numerous places on the internet (sda is my one and only drive), however it just says 0 byte written and has no affect

dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1`

dev null produces no data, just an EOF. /dev/zero produces all zeroes.